# What was the ancestor of the phrase 'person X' and from where does it originate?

Tags: etymology, phrases, generic-term

The phrase **Person X** - to mean a generic person - has been around for about 50 years:

[image: Ngrams, person X is lower than Mrs X which is lower than Mr X]

What term was used before it to denote a generic person?
Was it all John Smith et al?

From where does the phrase *Person/Mr/Mrs X* originate and does it have a link to the use of 'X' in algebra?

Comment: I'm guessing it comes from algebra.  Likely going back to Greek mathematicians.

Comment: Could whoever popped by simply to down-vote the question explain why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/?l=x) the use of X to refer to  an unknown person is from the end of the 18th century,

> - Used allusively for "unknown person" from 1797.

I think that the usage was later extended to refer to a  "generic person".[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=person%20X%2Cperson%20x&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cperson%20X%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cperson%20x%3B%2Cc0) shows usages from the 19th century of "person X/x".

From: [Equity, Also, The Forms of Actions at Common Law](https://books.google.it/books?id=CTk9AAAAIAAJ&pg=PA225&dq=%22person%20x%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr29ny69nPAhUKJsAKHYkPBq0Q6AEIGzAA#v=onepage&q=%22person%20x%22&f=false)- 1913:

> - If therefore — this is the simplest application of the rule — a testator has affected to dispose of property which is not his own and has also ***given some benefit to the person, X,***  to whom that property belongs, ***that person, X, if he accepts the benefit***  thus destined for him by the testator, must make good the testator's attempted ...